# GWT how to config to let one client connect to one server instance

Tags: java, gwt

How to config GWT let every page client correspond to one independent server instance, let server global variable will not be shared.
I found the same user using the same browser open the same page to edit different items, global variable will be shared, that is not good for my function. 
But when using different browser, it is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there is something wrong with your design.

Servlet instances are shared by design. It is not only correct that way, but necessary for performance reasons. You want them to be shared, otherwise your server will not be able handle high load.

Move state (the global variable you mention) to the client. This should not be to hard with GWT. Keep your Servlets stateless. If you need state on the server, put it in the database. If you don't have a database, there are other means. But in general the database is the simplest and most appropriate solution for server-side state.